# Parallelogram law, dot product

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Prove that if $||\cdot||$ satisfies $||u-v||^2 + ||u+v||^2 = 2(||u||^2 + ||v||^2)$ , then $u \cdot v = \frac{1}{2} (||u+v||^2 - ||u||^2 - ||v||^2)$ is dot product and $||u||^2 = u \cdot u$.

I've already shown that $(u+w)\cdot v = u \cdot v + w \cdot v$, but I have serious troubles showing that $(\lambda v)\cdot(w) = \lambda (v\cdot w)$.

Could you help me with that?

Comment: It follows from definition of inner product, or dot product, specially if given that your field is real.

Comment: Presumably $\|\cdot \|$ satisfies all the norm axioms?

Comment: @user57 I think he's showing that the inner product can be retrieved from the norm without assuming you have defined the norm with the inner product.

Comment: You can use $\|u-v\|^2=(u-v)\cdot(u-v)$ and $\|u+v\|^2=(u+v)\cdot(u+v)$ to get $u\cdot v$ easily.

Comment: @rschwieb Ok, great. overlooked it.